# Bottle using CherryPy server with SSL

Tags: python, ssl, cherrypy, bottle

I'm having trouble getting ssl working with CherryPY and my bottle app, here is my latest try at it:

```
class SSLCherryPyServer(bottle.ServerAdapter):
    def run(self, handler):
        from cherrypy import wsgiserver
        from cherrypy.wsgiserver.ssl_pyopenssl import pyOpenSSLAdapter

        server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer((self.host, self.port), handler)
        ssl_cert = "/etc/garage/pi.olympus.key"
        ssl_key = "/etc/garage/pi.olympus.crt"

        server.ssl_adapter = pyOpenSSLAdapter(ssl_key, ssl_cert)

        try:
            server.start()
        finally:
            server.stop()

app = bottle.app()
#bottle.run(app=app, host='pi.olympus', port=8080, debug=True)
bottle.run(app=app, host='pi.olympus', port=8080, debug=True, server=SSLCherryPyServer)
```

I can access the server at `http://pi.olympus:8080`, but not with https on that or any port.  I use netstat and it does not look like any other port is listening.

Edit: Cherrypy is 3.6.0

What have I got wrong?  Not that it matters this is on Ubuntu on a Raspberry PI.

Comment: Which version of CherryPy are you using?

Comment: cherrypy.__version__ is 3.6.0

Comment: You're probably facing the problem described in [this bug](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/issue/1298/ssl-not-working). The latest comments indicate the bug has been fixed, but there hasn't been a new release yet. I'd suggest to downgrade to 3.2.4 if you can.

Comment: (I've closed this question as a duplicate, feel free to ask me or others to re-open if you feel this isn't the same problem.)